# Stored procedure in derby

Tags: java, stored-procedures, derby

I am Trying to write a stored procedure in derby Database.
I wrote a Java file which executes as expected.
This is my java File

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class JavaApplication8 {

     public static void procedure(int uid, String Domain) {
        Connection con;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Love_To_Learn", "Mohammed_Numan", "mohammed");
            String sql = "Update Intrests set Points = Points + 10 where User_Id = " + uid + " and Intrest = '" + Domain + "'";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            int x = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.println("Finally");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I installed the jar file in the database by using.

```
CALL sqlj.install_jar( 'C:\Users\flipkart\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication8\dist\JavaApplication8.jar', 'Mohammed_Numan.JavaApplication8',0);
```

And

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath','Mohammed_Numan.JavaApplication8');
```

Created a Procedure Using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Final(IN ID INTEGER,
IN Dom VARCHAR(40))
LANGUAGE JAVA
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.procedure';
```

This gives me no error.
Now i called the Procedure Using

```
call Final(10006,'Java');
```

Even this executes.But the table is not Updated.
Any reason For This?

I even Called this using callable Statement.
The code is

```
CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall("Call Final (?,?)");
cst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(u.getString(1)));
cst.setString(2,v.getString(1));
boolean done = cst.execute();
    if(done){
        System.out.println("Done")
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }
```

And i always get Sorry..!
Where Am i Going Wrong?Please Check out.

Comment: The JDBC connection URL definitely looks wrong. But that may not be all of the problem. Have you, by any chance, worked through the examples at http://carminedimascio.com/2013/07/java-stored-procedures-with-derby/ first to verify that you have the basic parts of Derby stored procedures working properly in your environment?

Comment: If I run the java application alone it updates the table.So there is no error in the java file.I think iam going wrong somewhere while installing the jar file.!